# 2sxc News app: Show more then 1 category and role related categories

Tags: 2sxc

We are using the 2sxc module version 9.32.1 and the news-pro app version 3.1.
I am trying to make a view where I can show the items of 2 categories, but it seems I can only select one? And when I enable the function: Select more then one item, it will only show items for the first category selected.
How can I achieve this?

And I really want to connect user roles to the categories, and only show them when you are in then user role, how would I go about this?

I expect a list where I can show multiple category items.
and I expect a field with category where I can connect a user role to it.

Answer (score 0):

I Sorency - it's best to put each question into a separate stack-overflow question, to keep things clean for future users who are looking for one. So I'll answer the initial question with multiple categories.

There are two ways to do this - one uses Visual Query, the other code. I will just give a general guide here:

With Visual Query https://2sxc.org/en/Learn/Visual-Query-Designer
1. First make sure you understand what it does, as I assume you haven't worked with it yet. 
1. Look at how the first filter works - there you can either add more parameters (to allow multiple categories) or create a second stream with the additional filter, and then merge the results. So your query then has one list for the matches of the first parameter, and another match for the second parameter - and in the end it merges them together.

With Code you would do it in the razor file (CSHTML). There you would need to learn some LINQ and then work with the DataSource objects. This is much more technical, so I suggest you stick with the visual query for now.